# Fill missing values with missForest

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data

I want to impute values using `missForest`,

I have missing values in variables but not all.

When I do this it's really slow (that never happened)

```
mf_1 <- missForest(dtrain)
```

but when I do the following, it's ok

```
mf_1 <- missForest(dtrain[c(10,11,9,3)])
```

Do you think in the second case if `missForest` uses all variables or just `10, 11, 3, 9` to predict?

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please add more details to your question so others can help (ex. add sample data used so other can replicate the issue you are having). You will find these guidelines useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Subsetting the data frame will only pass those columns to the `missForest()` function, and as a result, it will only use these variables to impute the data. Here is an example:

```
library(missForest)
data(iris)

## We are going to have missing values in first 3 columns
## Introduce missing values 
iris_wih_NA <- missForest::prodNA(iris[c(1,2,3)], 0.3)
## Last two columns are then added
iris_wih_NA$Petal.Width <- iris$Petal.Width
iris_wih_NA$Species <- iris$Species
head(iris_wih_NA)

## Will use all variables to impute missing Values
iris_imputed1 <- missForest::missForest(iris_wih_NA)$ximp
## Will use only variables 1,2 and 3 to impute missing values
iris_imputed2 <- missForest::missForest(iris_wih_NA[c(1,2,3)])$ximp
```

As you can see, the second imputed data set only has 3 columns in total, as you have only provided it that much information.

As for the missForest imputation being slow, I think you could reduce the dimensionality of your data to get faster results or use the `ntree` parameter to limit the number of trees generated. But both of these options may adversely affect the quality of your results.